# How can i shutdown or exit from Docker installed in my Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: php, mysql, docker, xampp, ubuntu-18.04

I wish to start **Xampp** when i switch on my laptop having **Ubuntu 18.04 as OS**. ***The fact is, Docker already runs when i start my computer***. Therefore, it's impossible to start MySql and Apache. **it seems like the port 3306 is already used by Docker**.
I really to exit from Docker first for me to simply develop my app locally with just Xampp by activating MySql and Apache.
What are the steps i should follow ?

I'm on **Ubuntu 18.04** with **Docker version 18.09.5**

when i type: **sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start**

**expected results**:
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.3.3-1...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.

**actual result**:
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.3.3-1...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.

Comment: if you turn off your docker , you can run the apache server in your machine

Comment: yes that's right dear. but how can i turn it off please ?

Comment: are you using docker-compose ?

Comment: thanks for all the efforts, but the fact is i'm stuck to the same point on ubuntu 18.04. with the fact that i'm not able to shut down docker, to use xampp. if i come on windows, there is an icon of docker in the corner, when i right click on that, i'll just click on exit and therefore i could use xampp and start apache on windows 10. I prefer using ubuntu, but i need really help to solve this dear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop docker in case you are using docker-compose , use :

```
sudo docker-composer stop
```

In case you are using only docker :

First , type :

```
sudo docker ps
```

This will list all container . so copy the container id *(it's listed bellow CONTAINER ID )*, and then stop it by :

```
docker stop conatainerId
```

Comment: i'm not using docker-compose. i ran the command and i stopped the active container @mohammed, but i still have the same result: i'm not able to run xampp

Comment: what else could you suggest me ?

Comment: i ran your previous instructions, and no containers are active. so now i have 9 non active containers

Comment: You need to remove the containers `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

Comment: run this command and check what service is working on the port by **sudo netstat -antu -p**

Comment: port :::3306 : 31529/mysqld, port :::80 : 1476/apache2

Comment: what happen if you try to enter **localhost:80** on the browser ?

Comment: it displays Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page

Comment: can you know if it's apache on docker or your real machine ?

Comment: nginx a web server is in the list of images

Comment: retry this **docker kill $(docker ps -q)** , and verify again ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use different ports in Docker and XAMPP
For example: Docker Apache can use port 8080 and Docker Mysql - port 3307; XAMPP Apache and Mysql - ports 80 and 3306.

To do this edit your docker-compose.yml, set:

```
# for mysql container
ports:
  - 3307:3306

# for apache container
ports:
  - 8080:80
```

Port mapping should be set in format [host port]:[container port]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i'm new to docker and i dont know where to locate : docker-compose.yml on ubuntu 18.04, to edit that file. so how do i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also have the Apache web server installed in your system which starts on system startup.
After system start type 'http://localhost'. If you see a web page check a default path: /var/www/html
You can uninstall Apache if you want to use XAMPP for development.

Comment: it displays Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page

Comment: If you don’t want to use Apache installed in your system, just uninstall it and use Xampp